# Is it possible to execute celery tasks in a random order?

Tags: multithreading, redis, celery

Given:

Tasks get into the queue in aaaBBBccc format (where letter is a task that access to its own, shared between same kind tasks, resource). Workers to carry out the tasks are more than one but much less than the number of tasks. It is not desirable to overload the shared resource from armada of workers. The ideal solution is to execute different tasks at a time and never same. The best solution here I see is somehow get a random task from the queue, thereby decrease the chance of sharing the same resource.

Question:

Is there a way to control task consuming by workers? Or create a custom celery backend where SET is used to store tasks instead of LIST?

Comment: You can create a temporary db to store tasks before feeding them to `Celery`. Now from the db you  can send tasks as you  want to celery. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25709566/2698552

Answer (score 0):

No queues are FIFO and can't pick random from it.

> Or create a custom celery backend where SET is used to store tasks instead of LIST?

Do you mean that tasks aaaaBBBccc would do the same than aBc ?

In this case you can lock the task all other workers skip it while processed:

```
class LockableDwarfTask(BaseDwarfTask):
    abstract = True

    def _lock_key(self):
        return self.__class__.name

    def acquire_lock(self):
       # (use redis/memcache/mongodb), put a key with a ttl
       # if key doest exist, insert it and return True
       # else return false
    end

    def release_lock(self):
       # delete the key

@celery.task(bind=True, base=LockableTask)
def lockedtask():
    if self.acquire_lock():
        try:
            your code
        finally:
            self.release_lock()
     else:
       return 'Task is already processed by an another worker'
```

An another solution is to send each task to a different queue:

```
queueA: 'aaaa'
queueB: 'BBB'
queueC: 'ccc'
```

The you can decide how many workers you want in parrallele for each kind of tasks:

Tasks 'a' are very scalable, start many workers

```
celery worker -n wA -Q queueA -c 24
```

Tasks 'B' share ressources and don't scale that much

```
celery worker -n wB -Q queueB -c 4
```

Multiple tasks 'c' can't run at the same time: use the taskLock or spawn only one worker

```
celery worker -n wC -q queueC -c 1
# or with taskLock:
celery worker -n wC -q queueC -c 2
```